# Subtracting from all element of an array: VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am receiving a data. For storing that I have declared an array:

```
type fifo_array is array(0 to 66) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ins_fifo_array: fifo_array := (others => (others => '0'));
```

During process, this gets filled with different words(bytes). I want to subtract an offset of x30(hex) from all the elements of this array and assign it to another array for further processing. Obviously initializing it like:

```
type fifo_second_array is array(0 to 66) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ins_fifo_second_array: fifo_second_array := (ins_fifo_array - x"30");
```

not working. There is another solution like:

```
type fifo_second_array is array(0 to 66) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ins_fifo_second_array: fifo_second_array := (ins_fifo_array(0) - x"30",....);
```

Which is also not working. Please suggest.

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code does not provide enough information for us to help. Please provide a full code example and maybe tell us why its not working (maybe the error codes etc).

Comment: `fifo_array` and `fifo_second_array` have the same type definition. You can use the same type `fifo_array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
process(ins_fifo_array)
  variable I     : natural;
  constant C_x30 : unsigned := x"30";
begin 

  for I in 0 to 66 loop
    ins_fifo_second_array(I) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(ins_fifo_array(I)) - C_x30);
  end loop;

end process;
```

Comment: you missed the array index `I` in the loop